# JAX-WS: How to set up bidirectional proxy communication

Tags: java, web-services, proxy, jax-ws

I want to implement crash recovery in a web system architecture that uses JAX-WS where the client communicates with a middleware, and the middleware communicates with resource managers (RMs) using proxies (C --> MW --> RMs).

My solution was that if one of the RMs crash, it will let the MW know it crashed once it will have restarted such that the MW can try to recover or abort the current transaction. However, this approach requires the RM to have a proxy to initiate communication with the MW, and this creates a circular dependency between the MW and the RM, since the MW needs to know about the RM in order to compile because of the proxy, and vice-versa. How would you allow the RM to send a request to the MW?

Or is there another better solution instead?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by doing a quick hack: I sent the needed information encoded in XML over a http connection (Java's `HttpURLConnection`).

Another solution I came up with would have been to use TCP sockets, but the http approach was simpler and faster.